# Python - How to pull back a Specific Link from a website

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

Python noob incoming,

I am attempting to web-scrape a specific link from a website, although I am pulling back multiple and I don't know how I could define the code further to only pull back the one I want.
I believe the problem is due to their being a duplicate 'target' in the HTML

---

Here is an example of the HTML below:

```
<ul><li><a href="Link1.pdf">Weekly Metrics</a></li>
<li><a rel="noreferrer noopener" href="Link2.xlsx" target="_blank">Monthly Website Statistics</a></li>
<li><a rel="noreferrerenter code here noopener" href="Link3.pdf" target="_blank">2020 Overview</a></li></ul>
```

---

My attempt at it:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

raw_url = 'https://url1.com/'

r = requests.get(raw_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

monthly_url = soup.find_all('a', target="_blank")

print(monthly_url)
```

******** Pulls back 2 results *********

```
monthly_url = (url.get('href')) #this would give me just the URL inside the <a /a> code I want.
```

I would like to pull back ONLY the Link for the "Monthly Website Statistics" excel sheet.
Any thoughts on how I could define this further?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you share the url ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using findall to find all the elements with `target=_blank` which sadly has two.

You could try and use other attributs, bs4 lets you do so:

```
soup.findAll(attrs= {"href":"Link2.xlsx"})
```

Comment: Thank you! That print worked perfectly. Now just need to retain that information.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<ul><li><a href="Link1.pdf">Weekly Metrics</a></li>
<li><a rel="noreferrer noopener" href="Link2.xlsx" target="_blank">Monthly Website Statistics</a></li>
<li><a rel="noreferrerenter code here noopener" href="Link3.pdf" target="_blank">2020 Overview</a></li></ul>'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('a:-soup-contains(Monthly)')['href'])
```

Output:

```
Link2.xlsx
```